# Positioning inline-flex elements inside div

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to get two separate elements side by side inside one div but second one should be right side of div

```
<div className={classes.container}>
   <div className={classes.first}>
       First
   </div>
   <div className={classes.second}>
       Second
   </div>
<div>
```

I tried to give both `display: "inline-flex"` which sets them side by side. Then I tried to move second div to right side of container div with `flex: 1`, but second div didn't move anywhere. Then tried also give container div `justifyContent: "space-between"` and that didn't do anything either. So problem is how to set second div to right side of container div.

```
container: {
   justifyContent: "space-between"
},
first: {
   display: "inline-flex",
   flex: 1,
},
second: {
   display: "inline-flex"
},
```

Any ideas how to move second div to right side of container div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use `display:'flex'` in the `container` class. `justify-content` works on the flex display.

```
container:{
  display:'flex'
}
```

And then the `first` and `second` divs will take the required space/width and will be placed side by side.
For placing them apart use `justifyContent:'space-between'` or for equal spacing use `justifyContent:'space-around'` in the `container` class. Also, you can give the `first` and `second` divs width individually.

[image: Edit loving-tree-p9fs2]

Answer (score 0):

```
container: {
   justifyContent: "space-between",
    display: "flex"
},
first: {
   display: "inline-flex",
   flex: 1,
},
second: {
   display: "inline-flex"
},
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)